# How can I get all items in a storage map?

Tags: substrate-front-end, storagenmap

How can I get all items in a storage map? In polkadot-js, can we choose a storage map and give no id and its return all items? How can I do it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the polkadot js did not fetch all the items.

It uses [get_keys_paged](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getkeyspagedkey-storagekey-count-u32-startkey-storagekey-at-blockhash-vecstoragekey) to get the first <default paged size>(maybe 100) items.

This RPC accepts a key and a start key as params. So, that is how it works. Starting searching the first `x` items under the given key.

Tips:

After getting all the keys that you want, call [get_storage](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getstoragekey-storagekey-at-blockhash-storagedata) to get the key's value (generally this is a batch call).

You could make a loop like [this](https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/blob/18fef101dbe9a622f238dc69ace62bf7b10b3e79/src/subalfred/core/substrate_client/mod.rs#L38-L92) to fetch all the pairs.

Comment: Not quite correct - as explained in my comment `.entries()` (with optional params if map is more that 2 keys) would return all entries. What is correct in this comment is the underlying implementation that `.keys()` and `.entries()` use, aka via the paged interfaces.

Answer (score 9):

The JavaScript API provides the `.keys()` and `.entries()` interfaces on storage. This means -

```js
// returns all the entries, key + value pairs
const entries = await api.query.someWhere.someMap.entries()

// returns the keys only (decoded)
const entries = await api.query.someWhere.someMap.keys()
```

For a description of the above, you can follow along in the documentation. It is listed here -

- [map with keys and entries](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries)
- [more examples with double-maps](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/storage#how-do-i-use-entrieskeys-on-double-maps)

The UI calls `.entries()` for maps when the option is selected. Underlying in the API it indeed uses the pages keys RPCs to retrieve all keys/entries.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering how to do it in rust for use in the Runtime: You can use the method `.iter()` of StorageMap combined with the itertools method `.collect_vec()`.

So for example if you wish to get all accounts that hold balance in frame_system::Account, you would do as following:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools // imports .collect_vec()
let balances_tuples = frame_system::Account::<ParaRuntime>::iter().collect_vec();
```